Prove that $\mathbb{F}^n=U+W$
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field.
$
\begin{matrix}U:=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{F}^{n}\mid a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{n}\right\} \\
W:=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
\vdots\\
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{F}^{n}\mid a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=0\right\} 
\end{matrix}
$
Prove that $\mathbb{F}^n=U+W$
I'm trying to find $u\in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v=u+w$ but I can't think of a solution.

Try adding up the terms in $v$. This should give you the sum of the terms in $u$ when $v = u + w$.

You need to state something about the field otherwise the claim is False in general

$$v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n}{n}\\\frac{v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n}{n}\\ \vdots \\ \frac{v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n}{n} \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}v_1-\frac{v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n}{n}\\v_2-\frac{v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n}{n}\\ \vdots \\ v_n-\frac{v_1+v_2+\ldots+v_n}{n}  \end{pmatrix}$$
Idea: $$v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\x\\ \vdots \\ x \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-x+v_1\\ -x+v_2\\ \vdots \\-x+v_n\end{pmatrix}$$
Solve the equation $-x+v_1-x+v_2+\ldots-x+v_n=0$ to get $x$.

Thanks! Can you elaborate how you found this solution for next time I will encounter this kind of questions?

@CStudent I have edited.

Another solution involves dimension counting, a very useful technique for finite-dimensional linear algebra. The idea is as follows: if we can show that a subspace $U$ of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ is itself $n$-dimensional, it follows that $U = V$. (why?)
To use this technique, we should compute $\dim(U+V)$. There is a well-known formula for this, which you should try proving if you haven't seen it before:
$$\dim (U + V) = \dim U + \dim V - \dim(U \cap V) \tag{$\ast$}$$
So to show that $\dim(U+V) = n$, we just need to compute the dimensions on the right-hand side of the equation.
It's immediate that $U$ is $1$-dimensional, so to find $\dim V$, observe that $V$ is the kernel of the linear map $L(v) = 1 \cdot v$, where $1$ is the all-ones vector and $-\cdot - $ is the standard inner product. As $L$ is surjective, we obtain by the rank-nullity theorem that $V$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional.
Last, we can see that $U \cap V = \{0\}$, so $\dim(U \cap V) = 0$, so we are done by formula $(\ast)$.
